# IIS 6 Sending rules

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-6

I need to send all emails out as normal with the condition of gmail.com & gmail.co.uk emails. Which need to go via the google smtp relay service. Is this possible to setup on IIS 6? Basically 2 sets of rules.

Thanks

Comment: `I need to send all emails out as normal with the condition of gmail.com & gmail.co.uk emails` - That statement makes no sense. Please provide details on what you mean and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: As I said on the next line the need to go via the google relay service. The reason behind that is if they don't go via the relay they are either not delivered or delayed by a day.